# Is it possible to insert or update CaseFeed object?

Tags: case, data-loader

I'm trying to insert a CaseFeed item under a Salesforce Case through the API and I kept getting back the following error:

```
message: 'entity type cannot be inserted: Case Feed',
errorCode: 'CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY'
```

I'm using nodejs nforce library to make the API call. Am I lacking permissions to insert a CaseFeed? The reason I'm trying to insert CaseFeed instead of CaseComment is that I found that Data Loader does not give option to set the CaseComment contact reference. So every comment that I insert is appeared to be written by me. That is not what I want. Any help here is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

While the above answers are technically correct, they don't do a good job of pointing you in the right direction in order to do what you want to do. As mentioned above, you can't *directly* insert an item into the `CaseFeed` object because it's really just the feed that aggregates a bunch of feed items into one place. You can insert and update `CaseFeed` items using the `FeedItem` object.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130169/how-to-create-a-casefeed-uder-a-case

Answer (score 3):

No, [CaseFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casefeed.htm) doesn't support inserts or updates.

The documentation lists the supported calls as:

> delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve()

This kind of makes sense, as CaseFeed represents:

> "a single feed item in the feed displayed on the detail page for a case record. A case feed shows recent changes to a case record for any fields that are tracked in feeds, and comments and posts about the record."

So to create CaseFeed entries you would need to modify a tracked field, or add a [CaseComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) to the Case.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read the [CaseFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casefeed.htm) documentation, but in summary, the only legal operations are:

> delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve()

Since insert and update are not listed in the Supported Calls section, that means  you cannot perform those calls.